# Concatenate php variable in a location

Tags: php, concatenation

Depending on the variable found, I'd like that the user connect to a dedicated page.

Here is the part of my code :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;                          
header("location: welcome.php");
```

Instead of "welcome.php", I'd like to have "location: welcome_$username.php"

How can I achieve that ? I've tried with echo but it seems I don't understand enough php to find my mistakes.

Comment: `$file = 'welcome_'.$username.'php';header("location: ".$file );`

Comment: Try this :- `header("location: welcome_".$username.".php");`

Comment: You will get 404 error with that you might wanna do `header("location: welcome.php?username=".$_SESSION['username']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$user='test';
header("location: welcome_"."$user".'.php');
```

And the redirection leads to

```
http://localhost/welcome_test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`welcome_$username.php` Will give you a 404 Error after redirecting, lets say the username of that user is **John**

Your file will be `welcome_john.php` which I'm positive it does not exist on your file system rather user a query string.

Then have

```
header("location: welcome.php?username=".$_SESSION['username']);
```

Then on welcome use the query string to show different users what ever they need to see on welcome

Comment: Thx for your answer. But in fact I have only 10 users and so 10 welcome_user.php files with dedicated interface. It was the easiest way for me to do that.